# Java2WSDL java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, wsdl, axis, java2wsdl

I try to make WSDL  with Axis Java2WSDL class, and get an error that my target class not found.

Here are the steps that I did:

I started with a tutorial from here: http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Step_2:_Create_WSDL_using_Java2WSDL

A. I added the path to the files

[image]

to AXISCLASSPATH, and as well I added the path to the directory containing the files to the CLASSPATH var, so they look like

> AXISCLASSPATH='C:\Program Files\Java\axis'\axis.jar;'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\axis'\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\axis'\commons-loggin g.jar;'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\axis'\jaxrpc.jar;'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\axis'\saaj.jar;'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\axis'\log4j-1.2.17.jar;'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\axis'\xml-apis.jar;'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\axis'\xercesImpl.jar;'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\axis'\wsdl4j.jar
>
> CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\axis\*;C:\Dev\webworkspace\WSDLGENTEST\src\test\*

- i tried the path with no quotes, single and double quotes, to no effect.
- C:\Dev\webworkspace\WSDLGENTEST\src\test\* - path to the working dir.

B. I created a sample interface I1

> ```
> package test;
>
> public interface I1 {
>   public void f1();
>
> }
> ```

C. I built the interface and seen the I1.class file in

> C:\Dev\webworkspace\WSDLGENTEST\src\test\

D.I ran a command

```
 java org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL -o wp.wsdl
 -l"http://localhost:8080/WSDLGENTEST/services/Greeting" 
 -n"urn:test" -p"test" "urn:test" test.I1
```

and got an error of

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.I1
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
>           at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
>           at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.setCls(Emitter.java:2079)
>           at org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL.run(Java2WSDL.java:584)
>           at org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL.main(Java2WSDL.java:682)

- I tried to run it from the

> C:\Dev\workworkspace\test1\bin\test\

and also  from

> C:\Dev\workworkspace\test1\bin\

- I tried to run with

> ```
> I1, 
> test.I1, 
> test/I1, 
> ./test.I1, 
> C:\Dev\workworkspace\test1\bin\test\test\I1, 
> C:\Dev\workworkspace\test1\bin\test\test.I1,
> ```

params, always getting the same error. He just seems to be not able to locate the file.

- I updated the classpath with all conceivable permutations of the path and *:

> CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\axis\*;C:\Dev\webworkspace\WSDLGENTEST\src;C:\Dev\webworkspace\WSDLGENTEST\src\*;C:\Dev\webworkspace\WSDLGENTEST\src\test\;C:\Dev\webworkspace\WSDLGENTEST\src\test\*;C:\Dev\webworkspace\WSDLGENTEST\src\test\I1.class

still thesame error.

E. I compiled and ran a sample java hello world class just to check the java and paths work - the helloworld class printed what it needed, but the Java2WSDL does not work.

```
C:\Dev\workworkspace\test1\bin>java -cp . test/c1 Picked up
_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M 
ohoho
```

What can be done to overcome it?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of java are you using? can you also tell us what version of wsdl4j is used?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue then I appended my CLASSPATH (my classpath also target all the axis jars) with '.' the current directory.

> CLASSPATH=.

Then this worked out:

> "%javabin%\java.exe" -cp %CLASSPATH% org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL